# How to duplicate and rename a java package in IntelliJ in one step?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I fail to find a straightforward way to duplicate a package in Intellij under a new name.

I have a package `some.package.v2` and I want to duplicate the package to `some.package.v3` with all internal references to `v2` translated to `v3`.

IntelliJ does a good job of translating the references.  But I cannot go straight from `some.package.v2` to `some.package.v3`.  When I select the package `v2` in the Project view and I do ⌘C ⌘V, it asks where to copy the selected item.  If I select `.../some/package/v3`, it creates the copy as `some.package.v3.v2` because it copies the selected `v2` into `some.package.v3`.    So I have to rename the package `some.package.v3.v2` to `some.package.v3`.

This two-step process is a bit clumsy and I wonder whether there is a direct way.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way, so I will just provide it as an answer, if you have a better one please post.

To duplicate and rename the package, you should not select the package itself, i.e. `v2`, but select all the classes and subpackages the package contains.  Then press ⌘C,⌘V or F5 as before.  Intellij will ask you the destination directory which will be the destination package.  Just make sure to copy everything in one go, or you might end up with some references left on the old packages.